# Can't resolve Content-Security-Policy problems with ReCaptcha 2

Tags: apache, recaptcha, content-security-policy

This is, I guess, another variant on a couple of other notes regarding CSP and recaptcha; I've checked these, but they haven't helped.  Here's my situation:

- FWIW, the basic site is a rather heavily customized Drupal 7 code base.
- I haven't done any explicit CSP stuff in the site's Apache configuration, none of the Drupal modules are adding anything, and I haven't added any headers through my own code.
- When I load a page containing a recaptcha block, I get the following complaints in Safari (11.1.1):
  [image]
- In firefox, I get:
  [image]
- I get no complaints in Chrome.
- Regardless of complaints, the recaptcha is working properly, in all browsers.
- I've used the Chrome dev tools to look at the headers specified by the site's files -- the recaptcha files in particular -- but have found nothing about CSP.
- The complaints disappear when I remove the recaptcha block from the page, so I feel pretty certain that this is where the problem is.

So, I'm puzzled.  Is there any advice out there?  I must confess to not having much background in CSP, but I just can't figure out where the problem's coming from.  Thanks!

Comment: Slight update: I've checked out a couple of other sites using recaptcha 2, and they're showing the same messages.  So I guess the good news is that it's not my fault and I should just carry on, although the OCD in me would still like to get it fixed...

Comment: According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), Safari does not support `strict-dynamic`. Did you make any progress on this issue or still dealing with the OCD :) ?